# Symfony2: advice on implementing role per user per company permissions

Tags: php, symfony

I am in the process of evaluating Symfony2 for a greenfield project. One of the central requirements is that;
A user can be associated with many companies and each of those associations can have a different set of permissions identified by a role.

Has anyone experience implementing something similar or a perspective on how this might be achieved with Symfony2's ACL system?

Will gratefully receive any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm too late to the game but perhaps this will help someone else?

http://brentertainment.com/2012/02/28/contextualizing-your-symfony2-application-with-the-service-container/

In short, you can use the custom voter, then take advantage of the 2nd object which you can pass into the voter and use it to contextualize your security checking like this

```
public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
     {
         if ($this->supportsClass($object) && $company = $this->container->get('context.company')) {
             foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                 if ($this->supportsAttribute($attribute)) {
                     if ($company == $object->getCompany()) {
                         return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
                     }
                     return VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED;
                 }
             }
         }

         return VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
     }
 }
```